# How to manage empty jQuery Accordion Panels? How to disable click on Accordion Header?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using Accordionn jQuery Controls, you can find URL below:

Accordion: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Issue: How can we manage empty menus un-clickable; example - If I do'nt have any item on 'Section 2' menu it shouldn't be clickable. When i do this it's either make the next parent menu item child to previous one and distorted or if i only leave a emtpy `<div>`  it opens a blank menu instead un-clickable. Can anyone help?

Comment: if you don't have anything in the menu, why are you bothering to embed it inside a empty div??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-beforeActivate

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "accordionbeforeactivate", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

In function you can test `ui.newPanel`, if empty then cancel activation of that panel.

I created jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/npthU/1/

```
    $( "#accordion" ).on( "accordionbeforeactivate", function( event, ui ) {

       if($.trim($( ui.newPanel ).html()).length == 0)
          event.preventDefault();

    });
```

Used `event.preventDefault();` to disable opening of specific panel that has empty div.

Comment: Thanks @freshbm for the quick focus on the issue, I really appreciated. Let me try and get back to you at my earliest possible.

Comment: Sorry @freshbm, maybe your answer were also right but unfortunately i am unable to fixed. I am sure my lack of understanding, but somehow i've done this way around, please check http://jsfiddle.net/wru3j/

Thanks anyway...

Comment: Oh, I tried again and it works also... wow i got two different solutions now :-) Thanks @freshbm, i checked your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here an update of this code:

```
$('#'+_id).on( "accordionbeforeactivate", function( event, ui ) {
        if((($.trim($(ui.newPanel).html()).length == 0)&&($(ui.oldHeader).length==0))||(($.trim($(ui.newPanel).html()).length == 0)&&($(ui.newHeader).length))){event.preventDefault();});
```

Now It enables to collapse/uncollapse